# Which method should I use to do something between UICollectionViewCells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have implemented an `UICollectionView` image gallery. Each `cell` has some views and I would like to hide or show that views when I change the current `cell`, at least when the event starts. is there any method? or should I do something by delegate? I have `paging enabled` and  custom `cell` and `FlowLayout`.

I have done everything almost like this [tutorial](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/04/creating-a-paged-photo-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/)

Comment: Can you clarify 'I would like to remove that views when I change the current cell'?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to keep the current selected cell index in a local variable in your viewController, and use that index to perform any actions when selecting another cell:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedCellIndexPath;

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (![self.selectedCellIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
        UICollectionViewCell *lastSelectedCell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
        // Perform any change to lastSelectedCell before deselecting it
        [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:lastSelectedIndexPath animated:YES];
    }
    self.selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath;
    UICollectionViewCell *selectedCell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Change what you want in the newly selected cell;
}
```